# Extend PATH for QProcess

Tags: qt, path, environment, qprocess

I am working on a program built with Qt 6.5.1 where I want to extend the PATH environment variable to include `/usr/local/bin`. This is the code I have come up with:

```cpp
    QProcess *process = new QProcess();
    QProcessEnvironment env = QProcessEnvironment::systemEnvironment();

    env.insert("PATH", env.value("PATH", "") + ":/usr/local/bin");
    qDebug() << "env:" << env.value("PATH", "");

    process->setProcessEnvironment(env);
    QStringList environment = process->systemEnvironment();
    qDebug() << "env:" << environment;

...

    process->setProgram(programName);
    process->setArguments(args);
    process->start();
    process->closeWriteChannel();
```

and the problem is that the change I make does not seem to stick to `process` -- my second debug output is totally void of the addition I made before the call to `setProcessEnvironment`.

Comment: You want `QProcess::processEnvironment()`, not the static function `QProcess::systemEnvironment()`.